# Quiero obtener el texto de búsqueda de un p-multiSelect

Tags: angular, primeng, multiselect

Necesito obtener el texto te búsqueda de un p-multiselect

```
<p-multiSelect (onChange)="onChangeSucursales($event)" [disabled]="!fechaPeriodo"
                        emptyFilterMessage="No se encontraron sucursales"
                        selectedItemsLabel="{0} sucursales seleccionadas"
                        defaultLabel="Seleccionar uno o más sucursales" styleClass="change-multiselect"
                        [options]="sucursales" [(ngModel)]="sucursalesSeleccionadas">
                    </p-multiSelect>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito obtener el texto de búsqueda dentro del componente. cómo se ve en la imagen de arriba.

Esto lo necesito porque ese componente carga unos 5mil elementos, entonces yo pretendo cargar los primeros 50 y para buscar uno que esté fuera de esos 50 usar un botón con el texto de búsqueda.

Agradezco cualquier ayuda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trabajar con librerías de terceros es un poco restrictivo, no recomiendo lo que te voy a mostrar estas accediendo a los elementos del dom pero llegue a una solución que te puede servir los pasos son lo siguientes

Envías la referencia del elemento en el cual estas interesado escuchar el cambio de valor del input, en este caso el input del multiselect

```
 <p-multiSelect
  #multiselect
  [options]="cities"
  [(ngModel)]="selectedCities1"
  defaultLabel="Select a City"
  optionLabel="name"
  (onPanelShow)="onPanelShow(multiselect)"
>
</p-multiSelect>
```

yo lo envió en el momento que se abre el panel, como puedes fijarte envió la referencia de ese multiselect con #multiselect, luego en el ts

```
    onPanelShow(event: MultiSelect) {
    let aux = event.el.nativeElement.getElementsByClassName('p-inputtext')[0];
    aux.addEventListener('input', (event) => {
      let value = event.currentTarget.value;
      console.log(value);
    });
  }
```

de esta manera tengo la referencia al elemento hago una busqueda para buscar el input en este caso lo busque por la clase que identifica el input y obtenga el primer elemento puedes obtenerlo por lo que consideres correcto, el tagname que sería input o por un id, ten cuidado que esto puede cambiar de una versión a otra de la librería, luego me subscribo para escuchar los cambios sobre este input, consejo ten cuidado con los listener, destruyelos y crealos cuando los necesitas en este caso no lo hago pero se debería de hacer, te envio el stackblitz si te sirve, mucha suerte

https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-multiselect-demo-fnlzaq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

para lo que quieres hacer te recomiendo el virtual scroll que da primeNg para una carga ociosa de los datos (por demanda) con esto evitas que se carguen los 5000 los vas cargando de a 50 y los pedidos se los solícitas al api que te lo de por grupos de 50, deja la responsabilidad de paginas, buscar y ordenar al api, el front sólo debe renderizar

suerte un abrazo

Comment: Muchas gracias @Andres, excelente respuesta.
¿ Sabrás dónde puedo encontrar un ejemplo de virtual scroll para el p-multiSelect o el p-dropdown ?
gracias!!..